# Em um arquivo .bat (Batch) como renomear um arquivo usando variáveis, como %userprofile%?

Tags: variáveis, cmd, batch, bat

Estou querendo renomear um arquivo que encontra-se no Desktop utilizando batch script. 
A única linha que está dando erro é esta:

```
rename "%userprofile%\Desktop\Lista.xlsb" "%userprofile%\Desktop\Lista - %usuario%.xlsb"
```

Logo após esta linha, aparece:

> **A sintaxe do comando está incorreta.**

Pesquisei muito, tanto em português quanto em inglês atrás de uma solução e não encontrei nada. Fui atrás de páginas que explicassem sobre a sintaxe de ren/rename. Utilizei ren no lugar de rename, tirei as aspas, troquei aspas de lugar, testei tudo e nada. Sempre dando erro de sintaxe.

Quando entro na pasta, e executo sem informar ao comando **`ren`** 
 o caminho **`%userprofile%\Desktop\`**, ele executa sem erro:

```
cd %userprofile%\Desktop\
rename "Lista.xlsb" "Lista - teste.xlsb"
```

Isso significa que o rename não funciona com variáveis? Esta é a única solução?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entenda que o comando **`REN`** e o **`RENAME`**, não trabalham como o comando **`mv`** do ***linux*** (onde você define o ***path*** completo para mover ou renomear).

No **REN** você precisa informar o caminho do arquivo de origem no primeiro parametro, já no segundo parâmetro, você informa apenas o novo nome.

Como exemplo no seu caso ficaria:

```
REN "%userprofile%\Desktop\Lista.xlsb" "Lista - %username%.xlsb"
```

> Fiz a troca de  **`%usuario%`** para **`%username%`**, pois é o nome correto da variável do **usuário** em questão no **Windows 7**.

Testa aí e veja se funciona.

Comment: Bulfaitelo, muito grato pela resposta! 
Testarei quando retornar ao trabalho semana que vem e retorno para ver se funcionou. Só tenho Mac em casa. Poderia instalar um software de VM, usar uma ISO do Windows, mas prefiro usar o computador do trabalho. 
Quanto ao %usuario%, eu utilizei essa variável porque no início do código eu uso um set para input do usuário nessa variável, colocando o nome dele. Mas talvez nem precisasse com o %username%, o que seria melhor ainda. Vou testar tudo e volto para dar retorno. Valeu!

Comment: @JonesSantiago Vlw bom, feriadão! tem outras variaveis que pode ser útil nesses bat depois da uma olhada. [LINK MS](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cc668471.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Funcionou! A dica de utilizar %username% foi melhor do que perguntar para o usuário o nome dele e usar essa variável no nome do arquivo, já que é menos trabalho para o usuário do sistema utilizar o arquivo: quanto menos digitar, melhor. Obrigadão!